# braces and nginx rewrite rule

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

How do I use braces in nginx rewrite rules, e.g.

```
rewrite ^(.*)\.[0-9]{8,}\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|bmp) $1.$2 last;
```

running

```
nginx -t
```

gives an error, saying the rewrite rule is not terminated by ';', how can I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks quoting the regex works

```
 rewrite "^(.*)\.[0-9]{8,}\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|bmp)" $1.$2 last;
```